# Log Parser ORDER BY CASE statement

Tags: sql, logging, logparser

Quite a trivial problem here that I can't seem to resolve. I am using LogParser to analyse some telephone system CSV log files. I am trying to produce a graph of all the incoming calls between two dates, grouped by day of the week. I have achieved this, but I am struggling to have the graph display the columns in the correct order, starting with Monday. My SQL query that I pass to LogParser is as follows:

```
SELECT to_string(to_timestamp(c1, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm'), 'dddd') as Day, count(*) as Calls
INTO graph.gif
FROM C:\logs\*.txt
WHERE c5 = 'I'
AND to_timestamp(c1, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm')
    BETWEEN 
        timestamp('10/05/2012', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
    AND timestamp('24/05/2012', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
GROUP BY Day
```

It actually outputs in the correct order without any ORDER BY statement at all, but I think that the first column is always the day that the date range starts on, whereas I would like it to always be Monday (for easy comparison of graphs). What happens currently is it converts the timestamp from my log file into a string representation of the day of the week (for the purpose of output) and as far as I am aware there is no built in logic that 'Monday' is less than 'Tuesday' and so on. My instinct was to use a CASE statement in an ORDER BY, but LogParser won't accept this.

This is my entire LogParser command just in case it's relevant,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2\Logparser.exe" -i:CSV "SELECT to_string(to_timestamp(c1, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm'), 'dddd') as Day, count(*) as Calls INTO graph.gif FROM C:\logs\*.txt WHERE c5 = 'I' AND to_timestamp(c1, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm') BETWEEN timestamp('10/05/2012', 'dd/MM/yyyy') AND timestamp('24/05/2012', 'dd/MM/yyyy') GROUP BY Day" -chartType:Column3D -chartTitle:"Incoming Calls" -values:ON -config:MyConfig.js -o:CHART -headerRow OFF -iHeaderFile C:\logs\header\header.txt
```

Simply all I would like is for my results order to always start on Monday, regardless of the date range. Any ideas?

EDIT - This is the query with the CASE statement included in the ORDER BY.

```
SELECT to_string(to_timestamp(c1, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm'), 'dddd') as Day, count(*) as Calls
INTO graph.gif
FROM C:\logs\*.txt
WHERE c5 = 'I'
AND to_timestamp(c1, 'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm')
    BETWEEN 
        timestamp('10/05/2012', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
    AND timestamp('24/05/2012', 'dd/MM/yyyy')
GROUP BY Day
ORDER BY (CASE
    WHEN Day = 'Monday' THEN 1
    WHEN Day = 'Tuesday' THEN 2
    WHEN Day = 'Wednesday' THEN 3
    WHEN Day = 'Thursday' THEN 4
    WHEN Day = 'Friday' THEN 5
    WHEN Day = 'Saturday' THEN 6
    WHEN Day = 'Sunday' THEN 7
END)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your order by needs to look something like:

```
order by (case when day = 'Monady' then 1
               when day = 'Tuesday' then 2
               when day = 'Wednesday' then 3
               when day = 'Thursday' then 4
               when day = 'Friday' then 5
               when day = 'Saturday' then 6
               when day = 'Sunday' then 7
          end)
```

Alternatively, if your database has a day-of-week function, then you can do something like:

```
order by (datepart(day, <date>)+5)%7
```

This is the SQL Server syntax.  The datepart gives Sunday a day of 1 and Monday of 2.  The arithmetic is simply to shift the Monday to 0.

Comment: As mentioned I am using LogParser, and to my best efforts I cannot get LogParser to accept a CASE statement in the ORDER BY. I believe that it is only supported in SELECT. Also, I don't believe it supports datepart function, and I know of no equivalent. The error message from Log Parser for both methods is: `Error: Syntax Error: <order-by-clause>: not a valid <field-expr-list>`

Comment: Sure Log Parser's ORDER BY supports CASE. 2.2 definitely does. Can you post the entire query that gives the syntax error?

Comment: Hi there. I feel a bit silly questioning the man who wrote the damn thing, but I'm still getting an error and I'm definitely using Log Parser 2.2. I've edited my original posting with the CASE statement that gives me the error.

Comment: Try removing the parentheses around the CASE statement: _ORDER BY CASE..._

Comment: LogParser's CASE statement does not support this format.  According to the help file, the only format is
CASE argument <ANY TYPE>
      WHEN testValue1 <ANY TYPE> THEN replaceValue1 <ANY TYPE>
      [ WHEN testValue2 <ANY TYPE> THEN replaceValue2 <ANY TYPE> ...]
      [ ELSE finalReplaceValue <ANY TYPE> ]
END

Answer (score 0):

.....

```
`   CASE Day WHEN 'Monday' THEN 1
else CASE Day WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 2
else CASE Day WHEN 'Wednesday' THEN 3
else CASE Day WHEN 'Thursday' THEN 4
else CASE Day WHEN 'Friday' THEN 5
else CASE Day WHEN 'Saturday' THEN 6
else CASE Day WHEN 'Sunday' THEN 7
END end end end end end end AS DayNumber`
```

........

```
`Order by DayNumber`
```

Comment: Don't just code-dump; include some explanation with the code to back up your answer.